# Merging multiple data tables (or Replacing values from other lists) in R

Tags: r, merge, data.table

All, I hope you can help me with this query. Yes, I have looked up potential solutions here as well as other sites, but so far no luck.

I have a big data table (357 variables in total) and I need to match three of the variables there to their descriptions that are stored in separate lists. I have converted those lists into data.table as well, as I thought that that would help in the merging process.

So, for example in **dt**:

```
Market    Store    Product var-1 ... var-n  
2         1        1       XYZ GHY HHH ABC ZZZ
1         1        3       XYZ HJK III CDE FFF
2         3        1       GHY JUU JJJ JJJ KKK
2         1        1       HHH UUU JJJ JJJ HHH
```

When I loaded the data into **dt**, **Market**, **Store**, and **Product** were stored as Factors, but I converted them into numeric, as I thought it would help in the merge also.

In marketdesc, storedesc and productdesc the corresponding tables are simple, for example - in marketdesc:

```
idx   marketdesc
1     North/West
2     North
3     North/East
4     East
5     South/East
6     South
7     South/West
8     West
```

What I want to create as the final table would be a data.table that can stand on its own for further analysis, without having the need to look up the values from other tables, e.g.

```
Market       Store     Product   var-1 ... var-n
North        Chain X   Apple     XYX GHY HHH ABC ZZZ
North/West   Chain X   Banana    XYZ HJK III CDE FFF
North        Chain Z   Apple     GHY JUU JJJ JJJ KKK
North        Chain X   Apple     HHH UUU JJJ JJJ HHH
```

As data.table doesn't like by.x and by.y, I changed idx into the same variable names as the ones in the lookup tables, and do something like:

```
dt1 <- merge(dt,marketdesc,by="Market")
dt2 <- merge(dt1,storedesc,by="Store")
dt3 <- merge(dt2,productdesc,by="Product")
```

It's not the most efficient and elegant coding, I know and it's not the best method for memory management, either -- but my R skills are still quite limited. Does anybody know a better way to solve the issue?

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

**EDIT**:

The following creates the sample data tables (excluding var-1 ... var-n that are not needed for now):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Market=c('2','1','2','2'),Store=c('1','1','3','1'),Product=c('1','2','1','1')) 
marketdesc <- data.table(Market=1:8,desc=c('North/West','North','North/East','East','South/East','South','South/West','West'))
storedesc <- data.table(Store=1:3,desc=c('Chain X','Chain Y','Chain Z'))
productdesc <- data.table(Product=1:5,desc=c('Apple','Orange','Banana','Strawberry','Pineapple'))
```

Doing the merge constructs would require me to delete the original column, and then rename 'desc' with the old variable name after each step.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Sven - thank you for the suggestion. I have provided the code snippet to produce the sample data.

Comment: It sounds like what you're doing works just fine.  Is your goal to simply reduce the amount of code it requires?  I don't think having to rename and delete columns is inherently inefficient with `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the `sqldf` package for doing all of my table joins just because it seems exactly why sql was made. So for your example:

```
#convert all to data.frames, sqldf doesn't work with data.table (yet)

require(sqldf)
df <- data.frame(dt)
md <- data.frame(marketdesc)
sd <- data.frame(storedesc)  ## I realize that is overwrites the sd function, but too lazy at the moment
pd <- data.frame(productdesc)

df2 <- sqldf('SELECT df.*,md.desc,sd.desc,pd.desc FROM df JOIN md on md.Market=df.Market JOIN sd on sd.Store=df.Store JOIN pd on pd.Product = df.Product')

> df2
  Market Store Product       desc    desc   desc
1      1     1       2 North/West Chain X Orange
2      2     1       1      North Chain X  Apple
3      2     3       1      North Chain Z  Apple
4      2     1       1      North Chain X  Apple
```

I will update when I get a data.table specific answer, but this should do the trick for right now. You can obviously just convert it back to a data.table at the end if you want

This is a one-liner with data.table:
Note: I changed the column names of the desc tables to Thing, ThingDesc (e.g. Market, MarketDesc)

```
> Reduce(function(a,b) merge(a,b,by=intersect(names(a),names(b))), list(dt,marketdesc,storedesc,productdesc))
   Product Store Market MarketDesc StoreDesc ProductDesc
1:       1     1      2      North   Chain X       Apple
2:       1     1      2      North   Chain X       Apple
3:       1     3      2      North   Chain Z       Apple
4:       2     1      1 North/West   Chain X      Orange
```

where the function merges the two tables based on THE column name that they both have.
You can add suffixes for duplicate names (see `?merge` for more info). Just in case you get anything more complex

Comment: Thank you for the answer, James. I'll keep an eye on the availability of this construct for data.table as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the advice, all.

At the end, the solution deals with multiple merge while also taking advantage of the ":=" data.table construct. In my own data file, I realise that I also have to convert the variables that store the descriptions into characters (using as.character()), otherwise subsequent "merge" command will complain that there is a variable containing non-vector data in the data.table.

I also made a mistake in my example, for storing the **Market**, **Store**, and **Product** as characters.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Market=c(2,1,2,2),Store=c(1,1,3,1),Product=c(1,2,1,1)) 
marketdesc <- data.table(Market=1:8,desc=c('North/West','North','North/East','East','South/East','South','South/West','West'))
storedesc <- data.table(Store=1:3,desc=c('Chain X','Chain Y','Chain Z'))
productdesc <- data.table(Product=1:5,desc=c('Apple','Orange','Banana','Strawberry','Pineapple'))

dt1 <- merge(dt,marketdesc,by="Market")
dt1[,Market := desc]
dt1[,desc := NULL]

dt2 <- merge(dt1,storedesc, by="Store")
dt2[,Store := desc]
dt2[,desc := NULL]

dt_fin <- merge(dt2,productdesc, by="Product")
dt_fin[,Product := desc]
dt_fin[,desc := NULL]
```

The last step that I did was to clean up the transition files (dt, dt1, and dt2).